# on option select, show/hide table row and sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, bootstrap-sortable

This block of code verify if all of codes is checked. I am looking for a way to check if at least one of the codes is checked, instead.

```
function containsAny(needles, haystack){ 
  for(var i = 0 , len = needles.length; i < len; i++){
    if($.inArray(needles[i], haystack) == -1) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I have a full working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/v7wt5eop/

How to see this behavior:

1. In the selectbox click **Deselect All**
2. Check **A**
3. Line 2 and 3 of the table should be unfaded because **A** is one of the codes

And the rows that are with the class `row-disabled` should be at the end of the table. I am using [Bootstrap Sortable](https://github.com/drvic10k/bootstrap-sortable), but couldn't figure out how to do it. So everytime I click in an option in the selectbox it should re-order the table.

Comment: Do you want to know if any of the checkboxes is checked?

Comment: @doutriforce, I wanna know if one of the checkbox is checked. The actual code works if only All checkboxes are checked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `containsAny` should be

```
function containsAny(needles, haystack){ 
  for(var i = 0 , len = needles.length; i < len; i++){
    if($.inArray(needles[i], haystack) != -1) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

To sort every time you check/uncheck

```
$('.selectpicker').on('change', function() {
  var list = [];
  $('.selectpicker :selected').each(function(i, selected) {
    //Removed the irrelevant codes
  });

  $('.CodeCheck').each(function() {
    //Removed the irrelevant codes
  });

  el = $(".table tbody tr.row-disabled:first-child");
  $(".table tbody tr").not(".row-disabled").each(function() {
    $(this).insertBefore(el);
  });
});
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. Now I am looking for a way to sort the table. Thanks : )

Comment: I would like the table to sort everytime I check/uncheck the option in the selecbox. For example, If I deselect all and select X, only the second row will be unfaded, so all the unfaded rows should be on top, so the second row will be the first row. Thanks.